# log user out based on changed privileges

Tags: php, database, administration

I am a novice php programmer building a multiuser application in codeigniter.

Now, my boss has told me to look into the ability to log out people based on their changed user access privileges.

Fx. A guy is logged in as a semi admin, but has just been demoted by a real admin to regular user status. Now the semi admin should supposivly be logged out when that happens but this is where my problem occurs.

I can think of a few ways to do this but they all revolve around doing checks that will be redundant in most cases (this is a rare situation but it has occured, i have been told)

My best bet at the moment is to log all the active users in a session db and force them to relog in if their user role changes.

This however is going to generate a lot of trafic on the server for a rare "problem" as the user session data is more fittingly put into a regular session.

So my question in short is, how can i log out a user when his user privileges are changed, without working my server too hard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without a system that will keep track of what the session_id assigned to a particular user is, you can't undertake this in any regular way. The easiest way is what you mentioned, keep the sessions stored in a database because it's easy to manipulate them - if something changes, you have the session_id generated by PHP and you can either delete from the database or simply delete the session file, which will in turn force the user to re-log and inherit new privileges.

Comment: sounds like a plan though it is quiet a large overhead for just this one odd feature =/

Comment: Not really, it's actually extremely easy to keep sessions in a managed system such as a database. There are other systems like NoSQL's or Memcached that can serve the purpose of fast-access and lookup. Nothing prevents you to extend the session handler in such a way that it connects the session_id with user's ID (assuming you use a database to obtain user information) and then when a change occurs, just delete the session_id associated with user's ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if privileges have changed periodically, like once every 10 minutes, this should reduce the amount of "useless" queries and still ensure that there is an acceptable response time to a logged in user privileges being changed.

Comment: This would kill some of the overhead to process every request so i guess this would be the way to go

Comment: Its one of the costs of a stateless environment, only way to know the state has change externally is to check for changes at the start. I think there are ways to implement a "push" but that always needs a client listening (javascript usually, which means its not secure). If the period is not too short this would basically translate into a wasted SELECT every 10 mins or so, that's not a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript listener on the page then, when the super admin changes the semi-admin privileges to a normal user, trigger the logout event. Make sure that the app has javascript enabled, otherwise it won't work. This solution is used by many ACL-based apps.